# Configuring DNS records for Azure Websites

Tags: azure-web-app-service

The instructions on Azure regarding configuring DNS records for Web sites are easily misinterpreted, and people often has issues with configuring the DNS records required, or instructing others (IT) how to make the required DNS changes.

*This post is now obsolete, the azure documentation is great these days.*

Answer (score 0):

Multiple DNS records are required to assign a domain to a website in Azure.

For each domain and sub domain a pair of DNS records is required. The **A record** is required to point the domain at Azure, and the **CNAME record** is  required as this validates the Azure website you are associating the domain to.

For a *normal* website, you are likely to need 4 records:

- 2x A Records
- 2x CNAME Record

E.g.

`Type    Name           Value`
`A       @              123.123.123.123`
`A       www            123.123.123.123`
`CNAME   awverify       awverify.foobar.azurewebsites.net.`
`CNAME   awverify.www   awverify.foobar.azurewebsites.net.`

With the IP Address being your IP address associated to your Azure website,
and 'foobar' being your Websites name.

Here we have two pairs of records, because one is for the domain, and one is for the 'www' subdomain. Please **note** a 'awverify' record is required for every sub-domain and the follows the format of awverify.subdomainname.

I have built a small tool that outputs this information, so that it can easily be copied and pasted, for when you need to share this information with IT, other people, etc!

[Real Simple Azure DNS Record Tool](http://codepen.io/uniquelau/pen/yYowRb)
[Microsoft Documentation on this Process](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)

Comment: It is common to create the `www` record as a CNAME to the origin `@`, that way if the IP changes you only update one record.

Answer (score 0):

While working with App Service on Azure and godaddy as domain provider, I found out that we need below record to make it work.

- ARecord ( with IP Address )
- CName ( record for main site address
  ) and other CNAME ( for www )
- TXT Record ( txt record for main site
  address)

[ARecod Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRT8a.png)

[CNAME Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeFkt.png)

[Txt Record Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWjwv.png)

check the link for [more detail](https://www.scientistz.com/2017/12/how-to-create-scalable-optimized-wordpress-site-blog-using-azure-mysql-azure-storage-and-azure-cdn-part-5/)